# Node, React, with concurrently, EADDRINUSE :::8000 error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server

I'm trying to use the NPM package `concurrently` with a Node/Express server on the backend, and running `create-react-app`'s server on the front end. Here is the `package.json` script:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node index.js",
"server": "nodemon index.js",
"client": "yarn start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
},
```

When I execute `yarn dev` I get the following error:

```
$ concurrently "yarn server" "yarn client"
$ nodemon index.js
$ yarn start --prefix client
[0] [nodemon] 1.17.5
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[0] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[0] [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
$ node index.js --prefix client
[1] events.js:183
[1]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[1]       ^
[1]
[1] Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8000
[1]     at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
[1]     at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
[1]     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1367:14)
[1]     at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
[1]     at Server.listen (net.js:1492:7)
[1]     at Function.listen
...
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about 
this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about 
this command.
```

When I use `lsof -i tcp:8000` it returns nothing. I don't know what else to do. All help is appreciated.

Here is the server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const passport = require('passport');
require('./models/User');
require('./services/passport');

mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);

const app = express();

// enable cookies
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    // cookie good for 30 days
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    // authenticate cookie
    keys: [keys.cookieKey]
  })
);
// tell passport to use cookies
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// get the routes
require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

No matter what I change the PORT to, it gives the same error for that port.

Comment: Your server code can help here.

Comment: editted with server code

Comment: I fixed it with a kind of crappy work around. I changed the script to: `"client": "cd ./client && yarn start"` if it works it works i guess...

Comment: @MMelvin0581  why you are not using two ports for client server?

Comment: Sorry buddy, I'm not really sure what you mean. I'm following this from a tutorial dealing with hooking up React with a Node/Express server. The create-react-app should run on localhost:3000, the Node server I have set up, runs on 5000, which is why I was confused as to why there was a conflict in the first place. But I've got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're executing two times `index.js` which start a server listening on port 8000, which of course will trigger `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8000`

```
 concurrently "yarn server" "yarn client"
```

- `yarn server` runs `nodemon index.js`
- `yarn client` runs `yarn start` which executes `node index.js`

Comment: Gotcha. Is what I did the best fix? Is there another way to call `yarn start` from the `./client` directory?

Comment: I don't know what is your server structure, and what is the content of `./client/package.json`. You can run directly `node client/index.js` instead of `cd`

Comment: it's the package.json from the create-react-app, unmodified. The scripts: `"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }`

Comment: It's not bad what you're doing, if you like it and it works, go for it. It's just for development, so.

Comment: Like this it should work actually (the setup I am using right now): `"scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon app.js"
  },`

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json change the the client script to this `"client": "yarn --cwd client start"` it should work

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by running this command:

```
killall node
```